# How to select a column from a particular row in which I've used max on another column to determine the row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to determine the name of the player with the highest id on a particular team, the player with the highest id, and the player with the lowest id.  This is the sql I currently have.  It works, but I'm wondering if there are better/alternative ways that I don't know about:

```
select max(player_id),
       min(player_id),
       substring(
           max(
               concat(
                   lpad(player_id::text, 10, '0'), 
                   player_name)) 
        from 11) 
from players
where team_id = 201 
group by team_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

`order by` and `limit` is probably the best way:

```
select p.*
from players p
where p.team_id = 201 
order by p.team_id, p.player_id desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want the result for all (or some) teams, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (teamp_id) p.*
from players p
where p.team_id = 201 
order by p.team_id, p.player_id desc;
```

Comment: That works according to my original question.  Sorry, I forgot that I need some data from multiple rows and have update the question accordingly.